# Getting error message undefined index in php

Tags: php

So I get this error on my page:

Notice: Undefined index: url in /mnt/studentenhomes/brent.heynsmans/public_html/RMD/Taak-Rich-Media/index.php on line 14

i know that this code gives me that error

```
<?php
$playlist = $_GET['url'];
?>
<script>
var my_fn = function(callback) {   // <-- this is callback to be called later
var jax = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $playlist ?>",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        var song = $(data).find('key').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().indexOf('Name') != -1;
        }).each(function() {
            var content = $(this).next('string').text();
            jax.push(content);
        });
        callback(jax);   
    }
});
```

};

how do i fix this?

Comment: Difficult to find the bug... You need to share some more of your code....

Answer (score 2):

You can fixed this by:

```
<?php
$playlist = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'default value';
?>
```

Comment: Or if there isn't a default value, then simply do @$_GET['url'], and then add your own error handling/display

Comment: @Digital_Utopia, Nope don't use `@` the error suppression operator.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran +1

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran any particular reason why?

Comment: @Digital_Utopia, Here's a beautiful [**article**](http://www.sitepoint.com/why-suppressing-notices-is-wrong/) on that.

Comment: @Brotheyura it doesn't show an error on my page but in my console i get an error 404

Comment: open your html code and look at ajax `url:...` what data is in a variable  ?